# Python, Tkinter a mathgame how to make a point-system

Tags: python, math, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm on a simple project to make a math game. So far everything good, the user can choose to multiply or add. Then recives a multiplication to solve or a addition, then is give feedback. But I wish to extend my game, I want to make some kind of count/Highscore but not complicated only to give the user feedback in the simplest way, like if they get 5 answers correct in a row it will say in a text-box "Congratulations you've got 5 points". I'm not sure how to go further on with this project, simply I want it to be a python math-game made in Tkinter with a count function for each correct answer.

I'm using Tkinter & Python 2.7 for this, further on I wish to make a tutorial on this project to post on youtube. And all help is very very appreciated.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import random
import time

def fraga():
    global num1 
    num1 = random.randint(1, 100)
    global num2 
    num2 = random.randint(1, 100)
    global svar 
    svar = num1 + num2
    label1.config(text='Vad blir ' + str(num1) + '+' + str(num2) + '?')
    entry1.focus_set()

def fraga1():
    global num3 
    num3 = random.randint(1, 10)
    global num4 
    num4 = random.randint(1, 10)
    global svar1 
    svar1 = num3 * num4
    label1.config(text='Vad blir ' + str(num3) + '*' + str(num4) + '?')
    entry1.focus_set()

 def svar1():
    mainAnswer = entry1.get()
    # feedback på tom ruta
    if len(mainAnswer) == 0:
    tkMessageBox.showwarning(message='Skriv in några nummer!')
    return
    if int(mainAnswer) != svar1:
       tkMessageBox.showwarning(message='Tyvärr det rätta svaret: ' + str(svar1))
    else:
       tkMessageBox.showinfo(message='RÄTT!! :)')

 def svar():
     mainAnswer = entry1.get()
 # feedback på tom ruta
     if len(mainAnswer) == 0:
     tkMessageBox.showwarning(message='Skriv in några nummer!')
     return
     if int(mainAnswer) != svar:
     tkMessageBox.showwarning(message='Tyvärr det rätta svaret: ' + str(svar))
 else:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(message='RÄTT!! :)')

 def quit():
     global root
     root.destroy()

 #fönster
 root = Tk()
 root.title("Andrejs mattespel Quiz")
 root.geometry('700x700')

 # välkomstmeddelande
 label2 = Label(root, text="Hej!\n  Nu ska vi lösa lite matteproblem!")
 label2.config(font=('times', 18, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='white')
 label2.grid(row=0, column=0)

 #labels
 label1 = Label(root)
 label1.grid(row=2, column=0)

 #start
 entry1 = Entry(root)
 entry1.grid(row=3, column=0)

 # Omstartknappen
 entry1.bind('<Return>', func=lambda e:checkAnswer())

 #Knappar

 fragaBtn = Button(root, text='Jag vill öva på addition!', command=fraga)
 fragaBtn.grid(row=4, column=0)

 svarButton = Button(root, text='Svar addition', command=svar)
 svarButton.grid(row=4, column=1)

 quit_bttn = Button(root, text = "Avsluta", command=quit)
 quit_bttn.grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky = W)

 #Knappar multiplikation
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `score` variable and increment by 1 each time the user is right.
Now make a list named `highscores`. This should give you the idea of what to do:

```
#when user looses
if score > highscores[-1]:
    highscores[-1] = score
    highscores.sort()
    #Then display a list of best results with the current result marked or something :)
```

If you want to save scores, you need to write them to a file. The easiest ways to do so would be the `json` module. Just `json.dump(highscores, open(path, 'w'))` to save and `highscores = json.load(open(path))` to reload from the file would do when dealing with lists and dicts.

Comment: Thanx for the tip! Made a similar game in AS3 when I was studying at the university. But do you suggest I should save it locally then to a txt-file instead of sqlite db?

Comment: yes, I see it, but even though will I have to make the high-scorelist with tkinter UI? Then load data from the files into to the labels?

Comment: Bash-style? I'm quite new to python and still learning. Which is the smoothest and easiest way? I work as a DB-administrator & .net dev havent got much/1 month experience with python.

Comment: I meant in a terminal-like interface, which is nothing python related. If you do it with tkinter, then you should probably do everything in it.